# This is deleting my page, Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

For some reason my ajax success call deletes my page content and replaces the entire page with "success"

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Plan{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="form">
    <a>Welcome to planning</a>

    {{form.as_p}}
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content"> </div>
    <script>
        $('button#button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'submit',
                success: function(data) {
                   $('div#content').text(data);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my views being called:

```
def planning(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))

    form = planForm()
    return render(request, 'plan.html', {'form':form})

def submitplan(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))

    if request.is_ajax:
        POST = request.POST
        msg = "Success"
        print request.POST
        return HttpResponse(msg)
```

Can someone also tell me ajax is suppose to recognize my html ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('div#content')` is probably your pages id.

Change

```
<div id="content"> </div>
```

to

```
<div id="data"> </div>
```

and do

`$('div#data').text(data);`